# Add input field similar to "Qty" in create order page magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2

I need to add input field similar to "Qty" while selecting the products for order in admin Magento 2

[image]

I added input field as shown in the create form but i am not getting how to save it: [image]

Please help me for this
Thanks in advance
Reshma

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new field you wish to save the value(qty_in_kgs) in sales_order_item table first. Than by using the plugin, you can save the value in table as below

In Magento 2 without using fieldset you can also copy custom data from quote item to order item by using plugin.

create `di.xml` in your module etc folder.

**app/code/Vender/Yourmodule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="your_quote_to_order_item" type="Vender\Yourmodule\Model\Plugin\Quote\QuoteToOrderItem"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a class to your module and define a function. app/code/Vender/Yourmodule/Model/Plugin/Quote

Create `QuoteToOrderItem.php` file

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Yourmodule\Model\Plugin\Quote;

use Closure;

class QuoteToOrderItem
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param array $additional
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
  public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        /** @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);//result of function 'convert' in class 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem' 
        $orderItem->setQtyInKgs($item->getQtyInKgs());//set your custom value.
        return $orderItem;// return an object '$orderItem' which will replace result of function 'convert' in class 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem'
    }

}
```

I didn't give try to this but it should work. Once the value saved in order item table, you can show it wherever you want and proceed further.

Comment: Thank you Himmat But not working for me

Comment: Are you getting proper value for $item->getQtyInKgs() in plugin?

Comment: But where to add input field

Comment: In your above post you said: **"I added input field as shown in the create form but i am not getting how to save it."** Didn't you add that?

Comment: Ya Himmat I added that.

Comment: Your form field name is qty_in_kgs than in plugin you should get the valus $item>getQtyInKgs(); OR check by printing POST object (<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die; ?>)

Comment: It is working great now !

Comment: Actually the problem was not in your code it was in my input field creation

Comment: You are welcome, nice to know that it is working now for you. If you found my code helpful and it resolved your issue, than you can accept it. Keep helping other community members :)

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal I want to add a column for the stock in the above grid and I want to display the product quantity in stock in that column. so how can I do this?